# How change function parameters type with decorator in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, decorator

Have some way to change function parameters types according to decorator in Typescript?

**Context:**

I have this interface.

```js
export type Bar<T = any> = { 
    foo: T
    taz: string
}
```

And in my function I have something like this.

```js
class MyClass {
    something(param: Bar) {
       // do anything
    }
}

const instance = new MyClass()

const foo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
instance.something({ foo, taz: 'calling'})
```

So, inside `something` method I have `foo` as any type. What I want is to type the `foo` according to the parameter passed in the decorator, like below.

```js
class MyClass {
    @inferrerParamType({ a: number, b: number, c: number })
    something(param: Bar) {
       // do anything
    }
}
```

and in this way the intelisense recognize the types of `foo` within the function.

I want to do this, because I will apply some changes in `param.foo` inside decorator according with data structure informed.

Comment: Is there a reason that you would want to use a decorator for this instead of annotating Bar? `something(param: Bar<{ a: number, b: number, c: number }>) {`  Or making `something` a generic function?

Comment: I want to do this, because I will apply some changes in param.foo inside decorator according with data structure informed.